# Figure created in PowerPoint looks differently in a PDF file

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, adobe-acrobat, latex

I often use PowerPoint to make a figure, save it as an image file, load it in a latex compiler (e.g. Overleaf), and create a PDF file. The problem is, the figure sometimes becomes ugly when it is shown in the PDF file.

For example, I create a simple figure on PowerPoint like the one below. I use the textboxes to show the dimensions of the image. The shape outline of the textbox should be invisible.

[image: Screenshot of image editing on powerpoint]

Once the figure is created, I select the whole figure, right-click it, and save it as a PNG file. I attached the actual PNG file I saved. As intended, we cannot see any outline around two textboxes.
[image]

I load this image on Overleaf, compile a LaTeX code, and generate a PDF file. I used the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample_image.png}
    \caption{Sample image. The edges of the textboxes ("W" and "h") are visible when rendered as a PDF file.}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I open the PDF file using Adobe Acrobat Reader, and I can now see a gray outline around the textbox! I updated the Adobe Acrobat Reader, but this problem still exists. I'm not sure what is causing this problem. I attached a zip file containing the PowerPoint, image file, and the rendered PDF file.

https://app.box.com/s/dyg9cu4vp1wra78wgub8ngeqmnv93n5y

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting Case
there is a zoom level at which the "ghosts" disappear, here it is 250%

[image]

In Acrobat (depending on settings) they are not there at 100% but are at even 400%

[image]

The cause is a meeting of boundaries which is only apparent when looking at transparency.

[image]

You may note the image above says it is 24 bit (should not have any transparency?) however the PNG meta says it is a transparent image with interlace .

So we have at least one of potentially many problems when a PNG has Alpha colouration rather than simpler RGB. Said "Alpha" levels need to be %'s of black by default, we refer to such as a "softmask" when used in a PDF.

[image]

PDF does not natively support PNG so they need to be changed to one or two (or more) bitmaps and overlaid. Normally the registration of overlaid images is not an issue, but in this case there does seems to be a problem.

The simple solution would be to parse the PNG into a simpler RGB variant, because we cannot delete the mask without deleting the arrows ! and as RGB white on white should not produce any boundaries.

Here it is without transparency and also link to it as PDF https://docdro.id/hJrUQuL
again oddly the PDF is smaller than the PNG in terms of compressed data.
[image]

Comment: @K J, Thank you very much for your work! I usually save any images in the PNG format because I blindly believe that is the best way to preserve resolution. From now on, I will save images in other formats without alpha layer if the images are to be used in my PDF file.

Comment: @K J, That makes sense. Is there a simple way to reduce 32 bit output to 24 bit output? I'm sure one can do that with some python packages (like Pillow and Scikit-image) , but that may be a bit cumbersome to do that every time I write a report or a paper. If you know a handy tool, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out!